# How to deploy nextjs and nodejs web site

Tags: deployment, hosting

I am trying to host a web site that uses next.js and express.js. Since hostinger doesn't provide support for node js, I am wondering what would be the best way to host next.js web site.

I saw node.js and cpanel hostings and that just confused me more (I can install node.js in cpanel).
Should I just buy cpanel hosting from e.g. (a2 hosting), register a domain and connect everything to cpanel where I can use file manager to add project or there is something I am missing?